# Trying to write a struct in c to a file and then read it back later

Tags: c, file, authentication, struct, scanf

I wrote a code that can write to file a struct in a certain format easily.

But when it comes to reading that information back I totally fail. Here is the code:

```
const char *USER_INFO_OUT = "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %c, %s, %s, %s, %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf)";
const char *USER_INFO_IN = "(%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %c, %[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf)";

typedef struct user
{
    char TCID[100];
    char fullname[100];
    char email[100];
    char phone[100];
    char gender;
    char address[100];
    char password[100];
    char customerID[100];
    double balance;
    double savings;
    double debt;
} user;

user usr1;

void signup() {
    FILE *fp;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\t\t\t--------------REGISTER A NEW ACCOUNT--------------\n\n\n");
    
    printf("\n\tEnter Your Full Name:\t");
    fgetc(stdin);
    takeinput(usr1.fullname);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your Tc. ID NO:\t");
    takeinput(usr1.TCID);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your e-mail:\t");
    takeinput(usr1.email);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your Phone No:\t");
    takeinput(usr1.phone);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your Gender M/F:\t");
    scanf("%c", &usr1.gender);
    fgetc(stdin);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your address:\t");
    takeinput(usr1.address);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your password:\t");
    takepassword(usr1.password);
    printf("\n\tEnter Your password again:\t");
    takepassword(password2);
    if (!strcmp(usr1.password, password2)) {
        customerid(usr1.customerID);
        system("cls"); 
        char folder[100] = "users\\"; //here starts the File Writing Code
        strcat(folder, usr1.customerID);
        strcat(folder, ".dat");
        fp = fopen(folder, "a+");
        fprintf(fp, USER_INFO_OUT, usr1.fullname, usr1.TCID, usr1.email, usr1.phone, usr1.gender, usr1.address, usr1.password, usr1.customerID, usr1.balance, usr1.savings, usr1.debt); // here it ends
        printf("\n\t\t\t--------------REGISTERATION COMPLETED--------------\n\n\n");
        PlaySound(TEXT("Sounds\\signupdone.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        printf("\n\tYou succesfully created an account %s", usr1.fullname);
        printf("\n\tThis is your Customer ID:\t%s", usr1.customerID);
        printf("\n\nSave Your Customer ID to Log in to Your account later!");
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        PlaySound(TEXT("Sounds\\invpass.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        printf("\n\n\t Redirecting to main menu...");
        Sleep(4000);
        registar();
    }
}

void login() { //***this is the problem ***
    FILE *f;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\t\t\tWELLCOME BACK TO AVCI BANK\n\n");
    printf("\n\t\tPlease enter Your Customer ID: \t");
    fgetc(stdin);
    takeinput(usr1.customerID);
    char folder[100] = "users\\";
    strcat(folder, usr1.customerID);
    strcat(folder, ".dat");
    f = fopen(folder, "r");
    if (f == NULL) //this part works fine! if it can't find a file named "folder" it executes here
    {
        printf("\n\n\tSorry This Account Doesn't Exist.\n\t Contact us for further information or Create a new account");
        system("pause");
        registar();
    } else { //but when I enter a correct ID(file name) the program stops running. It crushes and closes immediately
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fscanf(f, USER_INFO_IN, usr1.fullname, usr1.TCID, usr1.email, usr1.phone, &usr1.gender, usr1.address, usr1.password, usr1.customerID, &usr1.balance, &usr1.savings, &usr1.debt);
        system("cls");
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t", usr1.fullname, usr1.TCID, usr1.email, usr1.address);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

I am trying to read the information I save into a file and place that information back into a struct to use.

But when `fscanf` function runs the program shut down immediately. Probably crashing. I don't know why. Can you please correct the code? I have literally no idea how to read a struct back from a file

Basically, how to read a comma separated file in C and attach values to a struct?
IMPORTANT:

```
const char *USER_INFO_IN = "(%[^,] %[^,] %[^,] %[^,] %c %[^,] %[^,] %[^,] %.3lf %.3lf %.3lf)";
```

I think issue is about this.
normally when I enter a format specifier in my VSCode it should turn into aqua color. but when I type in `%[^,]` which should mean read until comma, it doesn't see it as format specifier, `%` is red and `[^,]` orange. It takes them as separate things.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: The `fscanf` looks as though you pass the buffer sizes as arguments. That's wrong (but you would with the MS `fscanf_s`). You also don't check the return value from `fscanf` (the number of successful conversions). It's also not a terribly good idea to truncate floating point input: what's left remains in the buffer.

Comment: _"How to Read a comma separated file in C and attach values to a struck?"_ - Try searching for that here on SO. There should be _many_ examples to choose from.

Comment: The value `100` which you mistakenly pass to `fscanf()` as buffer lengths will be seen as a pointer to address 100: a sure way to crash the code.

Comment: We *really* should not need to know about your entire program (incomplete as it is: `takeinput`? `takepassword`? `customerid`? `registar`? No `main`!), as it should be almost trivial for you to create a proper [mre] for this issue: the structure definition and a set of hard-coded values for it, and some basic code in `main` that writes to a file and then reads it back should be enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Help others help you, and at the same time make your question more useful: post code one can compile and a few lines of data that can reproduce your problem. Note that writing something you can not read is the same as writing nothing: there is no way o be sure of anything. reading is the first function you write, not writing. Enter the data using your editor. Then read it. Then write something and try to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables to hold the format strings for `scanf` and `printf` is a bad idea:

- VSCode cannot make sense of these strings out of context.
- advanced compilers such as **gcc** and **clang** can perform consistency checks between the format string and the actual arguments passed to `scanf` and/or `printf`, but only if the format string is passed as a string literal.

You have some inconsistencies in the format strings:

- `%[^,]` is risky because `scanf` does not have information about the length of the destination array, hence can write beyond the end of the array if the input is invalid.  Use `%99[^,]` to prevent this.
- the `scanf` format `%.3lf` is meaningless. There is no *precision* field for `scanf`.  The *width* field is used to limit the number of characters read from the input, but the `.` in the format string is interpreted as an invalid conversion specifier, causing `scanf()` to fail.  Just use `%lf`.

Also note these more difficult problems:

- The output format uses a relax CSV like syntax where the string fields are copied unencoded to the output file.  This is problematic if any of the strings contain commas (`,`) as they will cause desynchronisation when the file is parsed back into the `user` structure.  Commas are unlikely for the most of the strings and could be rejected, but some addresses do contain them and there is no reason to prevent the users from using commas in their passwords.  You should use a more elaborate output format where special characters are encoded or where the strings are surrounded by quotes `"` (and where embedded quotes are appropriately encoded).
- the return value of `scanf()` must always be tested to detect invalid or missing input.
- calls `scanf()` to read from the user and mixing these calls with other input functions is confusing and error prone as `scanf` leaves unconsumated input in the input stream, possibly more than just the pending newline, so `fgetc(stdin);` is not sufficient, nor necessarily appropriate to discard pending input.
- reading input one line at a time and parsing the user input (or file contents) appropriately and fully is strongly recommended for reliable error detection and recovery.